# Starting powershell script from IoT Core UWP app

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-10-iot-core

I would like to call Powershell script (to set time) from Windows 10 IoT core UWP app running on RaspberryPi 2.

I already tried ProcessLauncher example from GitHub (http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/ProcessLauncherSample.htm).

Does anyone have any experiences running this sample with powershell script?

Comment: Do you get any feedback?